# Can I swap Bundle identifier between old project and new project?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I've registered a paid developer account at Apple and published an App to the Apple Store for my company. (For example: com.company1.app
At the next version developing process, I've started a new project and used new Bundle identifier(Personal Team) (for example: com.company1.testApp) to write and test the code. 
Now, I want to launch the new version of the app through new project and I try to swap the bundle identifier (write  com.company1.testApp in the old project file and write com.company1.app in the new project file.)

I got these errors:

[image]

[image]

Is this possible and if so, how can I achieve that?

Thank you so much and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, if your app was already uploaded with bundle ID "com.company1.app" it cannot be reused, swapped or anything else in any other application **even** if you delete it from App Store. You must provide new unique bundle ID in order to publish your new application on App Store. Or update the old one with new version.